# Site on Vercel looks different from viewing it on PC with browser

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, github, vercel

I deployed my website to Vercel to test it out, i made site with React and deployed it from github. Problem i have is that when i view it on my Xiaomi 11t seems like styles arent all correct like it looks on my PC when i test with responsive design using inspect element. Here are screenshots to see what i’m talking about:

Image from Vercel:
[image]

Image from Browser:
[image]

It doesnt seem to update Vercel very well. I dont know why, if anyone had same problem before please let me know.